# How to disable IPv4 and enable only IPv6 on arm Linux target?

Tags: sockets, dns, network-programming, embedded-linux, bind9

I am testing bind9 dns server for AAAA records. I would like to disable IPv4 to stop dns requests going to my default ipv4 dns server.

In the resolv.conf i have added

```
    domain mydomain.com
    nameserver xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx
    search mydomain.com
```

When I try to call

```
    getaddrinfo("mydomain.com",NULL,&hints,&res);
```

to resolve the
domain name to IPv6 address , I see error message
**"No Route to Host".**

The same program can resolve to IPv6 address when i run on the Ubuntu PC.

I have tried to test

```
    nslookup mydomain.com
    server:    10.1.xx.xx
    address 1: 10.1.xx.xx    dnsserver.com
    nslookup: can't resolve 'mydomain.com'
```

The nslookup command works correctly on Linux PC.

Is there any thing additional I need to do in the /etc/network. or else where?

Edit:

The issue is resolved with changes in the bind9 reverse zone configuration file.

Comment: You will first need to debug your IPv6 network issues before investigating DNS. And since it is not related to programming, this is offtopic here. You should maybe try [su] or [sf] instead.

Comment: Did you compile the kernel with the IPv6 option enabled? You can verify it buy running `ip a`. You should see at least one link local address (fe80::xxx) for the interface you're using. Alternatively try to remove the IPv4 address, set the correct route etc but those questions, like Patrick mentioned above, are better placed in those places.

Comment: @Stanislav .. Yes , the kernel is enabled with IPv6 and has local link address wth fe80::xxxx in the eth0 and lo ::1 and able to ping6 address. The issue is main ly about name resolution of my domain name listed in the bind9 server.